# Preserving formatting when adding non-formatted text to a cell with formatted text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Adding text to a cell that already contains formatted text (e.g. part of the text in red or different font)

I have a worksheet with cells that contain text formatted. Some parts of the text in the cell have colour or have bold/underline set.

I now want to add further text (which will not have any formatting). I am trying:

```
With BSheet
   .Cells(NRow, NCol) = .Cells(NRow, NCol) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & txt ' txt is the additional non-formatted new text
   .Cells(NRow, NCol).EntireRow.AutoFit  ' Ensure the whole text can be seen
End With
```

However, this removes all the formatting in the original text.

Is there a way of doing this without the original formatting being removed?

Comment: This behavior should not occur unless you have conditional formatting rules based on the cell's content.

Comment: no conditional formatting.....

Comment: Then you definitely have partial formatting in the cells, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

I thought *"this is an easy one"* - turns out it's not.

For info: The formatting is stored in the `Characters.Font` property of the cell. With that, you can access all single characters and the formatting.

When you record a macro and edit a cell that contains formatted text, you can see that the process is to set the text (which will remove all character formatting) and then format all the text again. However, this formatting is recorded with hardcoded positions and therefore unusable for a general solution.

Okay, so what we would have to do is backup the font settings via code, set the text and restore the font settings. But that's not so easy. Fonts are no simple objects, you cannot create a new Font object (to backup settings). After tinkering around, I came to the conclusion that you need to copy all the properties to an own structure.

I wrote a helper class for that. There is room for improvement, it mainly serves for demonstration. I named the class `clsFont`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type MyProperties
    ' Room for all properties
    Name As String
    Size As Double
    FontStyle As String
    Underline As Long
    Strikethrough As Boolean
    Superscript As Boolean
    Subscript As Boolean
    OutlineFont As Boolean
    Shadow As Boolean
    Color  As Long
    ThemeColor As Long
    TintAndShade As Double
End Type

Private this As MyProperties
Public chrCount As Long  ' Yeah, I know, should be private and have getter and setter...

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    chrCount = 1  ' Always assume that we have at least 1 character
End Sub

Public Sub CopyFromFont(f As Font)
    ' Save font properties
    this.Name = f.Name
    this.Size = f.Size
    this.FontStyle = f.FontStyle
    this.Underline = f.Underline
    this.Strikethrough = f.Strikethrough
    this.Superscript = f.Superscript
    this.Subscript = f.Subscript
    this.OutlineFont = f.OutlineFont
    this.Shadow = f.Shadow
    this.Color = f.Color
    this.ThemeColor = getThemeColor(f)
    this.TintAndShade = f.TintAndShade
End Sub

Public Sub CopyToFont(f As Font)
   ' Restore saved properties to a font
    f.Name = this.Name
    f.Size = this.Size
    f.FontStyle = this.FontStyle
    f.Underline = this.Underline
    f.Strikethrough = this.Strikethrough
    f.Superscript = this.Superscript
    f.Subscript = this.Subscript
    f.OutlineFont = this.OutlineFont
    f.Shadow = this.Shadow
    If this.ThemeColor > 0 Then
        f.ThemeColor = this.ThemeColor
        f.TintAndShade = this.TintAndShade
    Else
        f.Color = this.Color
    End If
End Sub

Public Function CompareFont(f As Font) As Boolean
    ' Check if we have different properties.
    CompareFont = (this.Name = f.Name) _
                And this.Size = f.Size _
                And this.FontStyle = f.FontStyle _
                And this.Underline = f.Underline _
                And this.Strikethrough = f.Strikethrough _
                And this.Superscript = f.Superscript _
                And this.Subscript = f.Subscript _
                And this.OutlineFont = f.OutlineFont _
                And this.Shadow = f.Shadow _
                And this.Color = f.Color _
                And this.ThemeColor = getThemeColor(f) _
                And this.TintAndShade = f.TintAndShade
End Function

Public Function getThemeColor(f As Font) As Long
    getThemeColor = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    ' font.ThemeColor may throw error when not set.
    getThemeColor = f.ThemeColor
    On Error GoTo 0        
End Function
```

Equipped with that class, we can write a routine that saves the formatting, sets the text and apply the saved formatting to the cell. To make it a little bit more universal, you can add a string before and/or after the existing text and you can choose if or if not to add newline characters.

```
Sub appendTextAndKeepFormatting(cell As Range, _
       Optional ByVal prefix As String = "", _
       Optional ByVal suffix As String = "", _
       Optional withNewline As Boolean = True)
    
    ' Save Fonts
    Dim fontCollection As New Collection, backupFont As clsFont
    Set backupFont = New clsFont
    backupFont.CopyFromFont cell.Characters(1, 1).Font
    fontCollection.Add backupFont, "Font" & fontCollection.count

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To cell.Characters.count
        If backupFont.CompareFont(cell.Characters(i, 1).Font) Then
            backupFont.chrCount = backupFont.chrCount + 1
        Else
            Set backupFont = New clsFont
            backupFont.CopyFromFont cell.Characters(i, 1).Font
            fontCollection.Add backupFont, "Font" & fontCollection.count
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Set Text
    If withNewline Then
        If prefix <> "" Then prefix = prefix & vbLf
        If suffix <> "" Then suffix = vbLf & suffix
    End If
    
    cell.Value = prefix & cell.Value & suffix
    
    ' Restore formatting
    Dim fIndex As Long, pos As Long
    pos = Len(prefix) + 1
    For fIndex = 1 To fontCollection.count
        Set backupFont = fontCollection(fIndex)
        backupFont.CopyToFont cell.Characters(pos, backupFont.chrCount).Font
        pos = pos + backupFont.chrCount
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can via VBA add text to such a cell and keep the format, I made a simple Sub that takes three parameters: 1) The cell to write 2) a helper (any cell) to hold a copy of the original format and 3 ) the text to add.

```
Public Sub AddTextAndKeepFormat(target As Range, tmp As Range, txt As String)
   Dim ln As Integer, c As Integer, fnt As Font
   
   If target Is Nothing Or tmp Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   If target.CountLarge > 1 Then Set target = target.Cells(1, 1)
   If tmp.CountLarge > 1 Then Set tmp = tmp.Cells(1, 1)
   With target
      .Copy tmp
      ln = Len(.Value2)
      .Value2 = .Value2 & txt
   End With
   For c = 1 To ln 
      With target.Characters(c, 1).Font
         Set fnt = tmp.Characters(c, 1).Font
         .Name = fnt.Name
         .FontStyle = fnt.FontStyle
         .Size = fnt.Size
         .Strikethrough = fnt.Strikethrough
         .Superscript = fnt.Superscript
         .Subscript = fnt.Subscript
         .OutlineFont = fnt.OutlineFont
         .Shadow = fnt.Shadow
         .Underline = fnt.Underline
         .Color = fnt.Color
         .TintAndShade = fnt.TintAndShade
         .ThemeFont = fnt.ThemeFont
      End With
   Next
End Sub

'E5 is the cell with the format, E1 is a helper cell to hold the
'original formating of E5, and a string to add
'After the execution the helper cell remains with the original
'value and format of the target cell. If want you can clear it.
Sub usageExample()
   Call AddTextAndKeepFormat(Range("E5"), Range("E1"), " - YES")
End Sub
```